# How to handle Spam (IMAP)?

Tags: 8.0, email

I am reading my Mail from many different E-Mail-Accounts on my Windows 8 Phone. Some of them use "plain" IMAP from simple hosters, so there is no server-side Spam-Filter-support whatsoever.

Is there a way to filter the spam from these accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Not on the phone itself. There is no junk control on the phone.  You could forward them to an outlook.com account and have it do the spam filtering for you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I was hoping for a better solution. I neither want to forward everything into my one outlook.com account, nor do I want to maintain several outlook.com accounts for e-mail accounts I already have. I hope another solution will emerg. However: thank you.